# Body and fixed div scrolling issues in Safari / Chrome / Firefox for iOS

Tags: ios, css, scroll

Here is a test web page:

https://codepen.io/zephyr103/pen/KOxgzL

includes code like:

```
body.no-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

It works in my MacOSX browsers (including the iOS/Android simulators in Chrome) and usually works fine in Android. It has problems in Safari, Chrome and Firefox in iOS.

When you click "Short Quote" or "Long Quote" it has a variable height fixed position popup with a transparent grey overlay that you can click on to exit the popup.

When you scroll (using touch dragging or mouse wheel) the popup or overlay it is meant to either ignore it (when you scroll the grey overlay) or scroll the popup content - if some is hidden. If none of the popup is hidden then it also ignores drags.

This is how it works:
The #text-viewer popup uses overflow-y auto. When the popup is active it adds the "no-scroll" class to the body element. This class has the css of "hidden" for overflow. This is supposed to stop the body from scrolling whether you are dragging the popup or the grayed out overlay.

On iOS the transparent overlay can be scrolled and when you scroll the "Short Quote" popup it also scrolls the body. When dragging the short quote popup nothing is supposed to scroll.

Comment: you should add overflow:auto !important for .body.no-scroll class

Comment: Hi I tried that - now it lets you scroll the grey overlay in all of the browsers - and it didn't fix the problems in iOS. See: https://sky-walker.net/temp/scroll2.html

Comment: i checked lastest version its working fine... wihch one is you tested

Comment: Try using the mouse wheel on the grey overlay - for me it is allowing the body to scroll

Comment: pls use touch bro.. how should use you mouse wheel in mobile? think UI..

Comment: I'm saying that my original test scrolling web page fully works on Android mobile devices, simulated mobile devices in Chrome DevTools and desktop browsers including using the mouse wheel. When I changed it to "overflow:auto !important" the scrolling stopped working properly. I want it to handle the mouse wheel since it already did in my original version. Also I did use touch when testing the new version in iOS Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for iOS Safari, Chrome and Firefox

https://codepen.io/zephyr103/pen/mNzoGE

I removed the no-scroll class and styling for the body element.

When the popup is being shown:

```
var targetElement = document.querySelector("#text-viewer");
bodyScrollLock.disableBodyScroll(targetElement);
```

When the popup is being hidden:

```
bodyScrollLock.clearAllBodyScrollLocks();
```

The js file:

https://github.com/willmcpo/body-scroll-lock/tree/master/lib

Usage:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-scroll-lock

The only problem is that the long quote popup doesn't shrink to fit on the screen in iOS Safari and Chrome (sometimes is ok in iOS Firefox)

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you ought to do for Safari is to add

```
body.no-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Also, when you open popup add to the body this code as well in JavaScript

```
body.ontouchstart = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
 };
```

If you want to remove scrollbar then you need to calculate its width

```
const documentWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
const windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
const scrollBarWidth = windowWidth - documentWidth;
```

and then add padding right to body with the `${scrollBarWidth}px`

Comment: Hi I created a fork of the codepen for your first suggestion: (-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch) https://codepen.io/zephyr103/pen/LwgbJg For the second suggestion I want to have old fashioned javascript/jQuery code (not (e) => { ). I don't have a problem with there being a scrollbar - I'm just talking about whether things scroll or not. The original codepen works fine in Safari for MacOSX and the iOS simulators in Chrome DevTools.

Answer (score -1):

After close the dialog, do this for iphone

```
$('html').removeAttr('style');
$('body').removeAttr('style');
```